# auto setup/deploy development environment

Tags: linux, development-environment

I want to make a script of sorts such that I can automate the mundane tasks that I do to setup my linux box after a clean install. These steps are namely:

1. Install perforce(as I work with perforce), or git and checkout code - This requires the user to enter a user/password

   Install software such as sun-jdk, maven, mysql, tomcat, etc

   Install eclipse and a couple of other plugins

   Mount a remote drive to local disk and create a copy of the data from that mount to local disk

There are other couple of task and the target system is mostly ubuntu/debian? How can I do this, I know preseed file is an option but how do i do user input and stuff. Pls help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/) which is

> a Python (2.5 or higher) library and command-line tool for streamlining the use of SSH for application deployment or systems administration tasks.

You can write a `fabfile` with the various tasks you need, and then just run it against your freshly installed machine to configure the environment.

Answer (score -1):

[Gitpod.io](https://www.gitpod.io) provides automated dev environments as a service. 
It is not only providing a full terminals based on Docker but also prebuilds your git branches, so you are ready to code immediately.